# Como editar o titulo de TODOS os alerts no ionic app, e não somente um?

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova, controller, alert

Seguindo a documentação do ionic, consigo editar o título de um alert, usando o ensinado no link seguinte:[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

Porém, quando o alert é disparado de dentro de um iframe, ele é mostrado como um alert "natural" do android, algo que não combina com meu app. Como consigo realizar uma mudança em TODOS os títulos de TODOS os alerts, mesmo aqueles que são disparados pelo iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um app utilizando `ionic v1` utilizando as mesma propriedades da documentação do `ionic v3` e funcionou pra mim. Segue a abaixo o que eu utilizei:

```
$ionicPopup.confirm({
      title: titulo,
      subTitle: subtitle,
      template: 
      `<style>
        .popup{
          border-radius: 7px !important;
        }
        .popup-head { 
          background: ${backgroundTitulo} !important;
          border-top-left-radius: 7px !important;
          border-top-right-radius: 7px !important; 
        }
        .popup-title {
          color: ${corTitulo} !important;
        }
        .popup-sub-title{
          color: ${corTitulo} !important;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .popup-body{
          background: ${background} !important;
          /*color:#fff !important;
          font-size:24px !important;*/
          text-align: center;
        }
        .popup-buttons{
          background: ${background} !important;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 7px !important;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 7px !important;
        }
        .popup-buttons .button {
          color: ${corBotaoTexto} !important;
        }
        .popup-buttons .button {
          background: ${corBotao} !important;
          color: ${corBotaoTexto} !important;
          box-shadow: none !important;
          border-radius: 5px !important;
        }
      </style>
      <p>${message}</p>
      `
      ,buttons: [
        { // Array[Object] (optional). Buttons to place in the popup footer.
          text: 'Não',
          type: 'button-default',
          onTap: function(e) {
            if( cancelCallback != null){
              cancelCallback(e);
            }
            return e;
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Sim',
          type: 'button-positive',
          onTap: function(e) {
            if(confirmCallback != null){
              confirmCallback(e);
            }
            return e;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  };
```

Obs: o que está dentro de `${...}`, que é o interpolador de string do javascript ES2015, são variáveis javascript que eu define em meu código.